# Cayley graphs of isomorphic groups

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is isomorphic to $D_6$ then do both the groups have the same Cayley graph. If not then can anyone help me solve this problem

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394338/cayley-graph-of-a-group-isomorphic-to-d6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Cayley color graph is determined by the choice of generators for a group $G$. Thus if $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ is a set of generators for$D_6$(notice you do not need to choose a minimal set here) and there is an isomorphism $\Phi:D_6\to G$ then the Cayley color graph of $G$ using generators$\{\Phi(e_1),\Phi(e_2),...,\Phi(e_n)\}$ will be the same as the Cayley color graph of $D_6$ using the first set of generators.